# ¿Por qué en España "estar podrido de dinero" quiere decir tener mucho?

Tags: expresiones, españa

Cuántas veces habremos oído en España expresiones del tipo:

> Ese señor está forrado. Desde que vendió la empresa a esa multinacional, dicen que **está podrido de dinero**.

Ya lo recoge el DRAE:

> [**podrido**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TUJoCcv)
>   Del part. de *podrir*.
>   1. adj. Dicho de una persona o de una institución: Corrompida o dominada por la inmoralidad.
>
> **estar podrido, da de**
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Tener en gran abundancia dinero u otros bienes materiales. Están podridos de dinero.

Mirando en el Diccionario de americanismos me encuentro con que, además, tiene distintas acepciones en otros lugares:

> [**podrido, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=q7HqNd4yhx0AT30chfV%7CcUczkHidix0A4FUyg8R).
>   I.  1.  adj. Ni, CR, Ec, Bo:E, Py, Ar, Ur. Referido a persona, harta, molesta, enfadada. pop + cult → espon.
>   II. 1.  adj. Ch. Referido a cosa, de mala calidad. pop.
>   III.    1.  adj. Ho. Referido a persona, drogadicta.

Es decir, que alguien *podrido* en el cono sur viene a ser alguien enfadado.

Y, además, la primera acepción ofrece otras sorpresas en cuanto a significados regionales:

> **podrida**.
>   I.  1.  f. Bo, Py. Bronca, riña o disputa ruidosa. pop + cult → espon.
>   II. 1.  f. Cu. Asunto difícil, molesto o complicado.
>   a. ǁ    la ~. loc. sust. Bo, Ar, Ur. Pelea, situación violenta o caótica. pop + cult → espon.

Pero ninguno de ellos vuelve a la acepción de "tener mucho de algo", especialmente dinero. ¿Alguien sabe de dónde viene? ¿Acaso es porque cuando tienes mucho de algo se te puede pudrir? Si fuera esto, diríamos *podrído con dinero*.

Comment: Esto es un completo palo de ciego o conjetura por mi parte: Se necesita poco para que la fruta se pudra, pero en cambio para que se pudra la madera harían falta buenas cantidades de agua, y tampoco va a suceder en un espacio corto de tiempo. Podría decirse que la madera ha acumulado tanta agua que ha llegado a pudrirse. Quizá pueda ser una analogía de "Acumular tanto de algo que llega a pudrirse".

Comment: Yo generalmente suelo decir que está "forrado" de dinero. "Podrido" me da una connotación negativa. La otra acepción de "estar podrido" es cuando una institución está corrupta, que suele ser habitualmente cuando sus miembros se están lucrando indebidamente (muchos ejemplos de esos tenemos en España últimamente). Ese mismo sentido de "estar podrido" puede ser el que aplique a las personas excesivamente ricas (es fácil pensar que su riqueza se haya debido a una inmoralidad o "podredumbre").

Comment: En Colombia se también se usa esta frase, nunca me he cuestionado su origen, sin embargo una frase aún más común es 'estar picho en plata' (siendo picho un sinónimo de descompuesto o podrido), sinceramente pese a la frecuencia con la que se usa, desconozco el origen o la explicación de el uso de la palabra. En mi opinión se usa, puesto que cuando se tiene algo abundancia o demasía de cualquier cosa pasa a ser perjudicial, sin embargo no me suena correcto: "ese hombre esta picho/podrido en problemas", "estoy picho/podrido de trabajos".

Comment: ¿Puede ser porque el dinero corrompe?

Comment: Quería añadir que en inglés existen las expresiones _filthy rich_ y _stink rich_, y en portugués _podre de rico_.

Comment: También en Argentina: "podrido en plata"

Comment: Las expresiones que menciona @ebhyjeyb sugieren una propensión que es probablemente universal de la gente, de despreciar lo que envidian, especialmente cuando tienen poca posibilidad.de alcanzarlo. En este contexto, ¿sabe alguién si existe en castellano una equivalente al inglés "sour grapes?"

Comment: @cuevero "Las uvas están verdes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Argentina se dice más bien *estar podrido **en** guita* (*guita* = "dinero"), aunque también es posible escucharlo con *de*. Sin embargo, fuera de ese contexto *estar podrido* efectivamente significa "estar harto, molesto, cansado", y se usa siempre con un objeto en *de*:

> *Ya estoy podrido de trabajar así.*
>   *Mi hija está podrida de esa situación de inseguridad.*

*Podrido* tiene en estos casos y en el de la pregunta un sentido y un uso paralelo al de palabras como *lleno* y *harto*: una abundancia que ya es exceso, o que es tan grande que molesta. En el caso del dinero quizá no moleste a la persona que lo tiene pero sí les parece excesivo a los demás.

El misterio aquí es por qué se asocia podredumbre con exceso. ¿Quizá porque cuando uno tiene muchas cosas acumuladas y sin usar, se le termina pudriendo la mayor parte? ¿Quizá porque la podredumbre se asocia con una efusión?

Comment: En Colombia también usamos **en** y la expresión mas común es algo como así: _Ese señor esta podrido en la plata_

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión y dado que no he podido cotejarlo en ningún sitio.

> Estar podrido de dinero = Tener mucho dinero.

El motivo es sencillo. Si riegas mucho una planta que está en una maceta se pudre. Se pudre porque el agua se estanca, lo cuál forma bacterias. Las bacterias proliferan cuando hay humedad y sol, las plantas necesitan sol por lo que generalmente será necesario el solo para que crezcan. **Así se forma un círculo vicioso en el que elementos beneficiosos se vuelven perjudiciales**. El agua y el sol producen que la raiz de la planta se pudra.

**Ese mismo proceso ocurre con el dinero. El dinero no es algo malo, sino necesario para poder vivir pero el dinero corrompe, al igual que el agua estancada pudre la raíz.**

En muchos casos una persona que tiene demasiado dinero se dice que está "podrida de dinero" porque tiene tanto que ha hecho que no sea como los demás. La forma que tiene de ver las cosas es distinta.

Answer (score 0):

En Español hace más de 5 siglos que se usa la palabra podrido/a para referirse a algo que no esta corrompido. Un ejemplo es la receta llamada olla podrida, que es un plato contundente con gran cantidad de ingredientes desde ortaluzas a multiples piezas o elaboraciones carnicas. Se dice que en ese caso la denominación podrida derivaría de poderida (similar a empoderada) y haría referencia a la riqueza de productos en el plato. De similar modo, podrido de dinero hace referencia a la riqueza economica y ninguna relación tiene con la putrefacción.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio! Es una respuesta interesante la que das, pero fíjate que al contrario que otras respuestas que dicen que no han podido cotejar sus respuestas y que son opiniones, tú parece que afirmas categóricamente lo que dices. ¿Podrías darnos alguna fuente o cita que corrobore lo que afirmas? Así tu respuesta quedaría mucho más profesional. Si no es así, por favor indica en la respuesta la condición de opinión. Consulta la sección [answer] para más información. ¡Esperamos ver más aportaciones tuyas!

Answer (score -2):

Es mucho mas simple: podrido = harto = mas que suficiente. Cuando uno dice que esta harto de algo es porque ya tuvo mas que suficiente de ese algo. En este caso se aplica de eforma similar. La expresion podrido de dinero, o en dinero, o en guita esta indicando que tiene dinero mas que suficiente.

Comment: Yo puedo hartarme de algo (Estoy harto de comer arroz; estoy harto de ver a este famosete en la tele; estoy harto de oir "La Macarena"; estoy harto de que la gente me empuje en el metro), pero no diría que estoy "podrido" de ello. Eso de `podrido = harto` no vale para todos los contextos. `Cuando uno dice que esta harto de algo es porque ya tuvo mas que suficiente de ese algo` -> Cierto (en eso se basan las respuestas preexistentes), pero hartazo no necesariamente implica podredumbre.